# concatenating a string to the end of a a returned json list python

Tags: arrays, json, string, list, concatenation

Hi I am using the below code to return some json from a url and it returns the results as a list just how I want, however I want to add a string to each of the returned results.

Printing n in a for loop works but I dont know where to add the string I want to add to the result, everything I have tried throws errors about mixing stings with lists. I have read about arrays and can add data to the array and show onlly certain results but am not sure where to start with adding data to the result.

for example.

I get

```
Result1
Result2
Result3, 
etc,
```

however I want to return

```
String Result1
String Result2
String Result3.
```

the string will be constant but the result will be what has been returned.

```
import urllib.request as request
import json


with request.urlopen('https://jsondatalist') as response:
    if response.getcode() == 200:
        source = response.read()
        data = json.loads(source)

        for n in (data):
            print (n)

    else:
        print('An error occured while attempting to retrieve data from source')
```

Comment: Can you post sample data from the url?

Comment: sure if I dont use a for loop it returns ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result5'], but with the loop all are in a list without the quotes (I can store the data in a text file nad print it just am not sure how to add anything to it)

Comment: Post the sample json data. Not just the output of for loop. It's easier to know the problem in that way

Comment: sorry if I wasnt clear ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result5'] is how the data is returned (I have had to change the actual data but this is how it comes back)

Comment: So, the value of the variable `source` is `['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result5']`?

Comment: yes if I print source instead of data it comes back with this b'['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result5'] it has a "b'" in front.

Comment: I just checked in firefox and it returns each results in double quotes instead of singles, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about string interpolation.

on python > 3.6 you can do `print(f"String {n}")`

on older versions of python you can do `print("String {}".format(n))`

Comment: im on 3.6.3 so i will give that a go, thanks for helping, ill give it a try and read about string interpolation.  I wasnt sure how to word it. will report back.

Comment: Thanks again, worked perfectly.  as I said, Ill read up about that now I know the term.